# Theory of group representation for compact groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, topological-groups

I write here because some experts could help on that. It is very well known (at least for me) many reference books on linear representations of finite groups (for instance, the very classical and excellent book by Serre).

In my research I would like to go a little beyond this theory and go through the same methodology for compact (possibly) infinite groups.

Is there some reference for a general mathematics researcher dealing with this topic?

My motivation is the following: due a very classical result due to Frobenius, the irreducible representations of the group $SL_2(F_p)$ have all large dimension. So, is there an analogue result for, for instance, $SL_2(K)$, where $K$ in an infinite field (I am thinking in either the reals or the complex numbers).

Comment: Including compact Lie groups or just compact topological groups?

Comment: Almost everything about the representation theory of arbitrary finite groups has a direct analogue for compact groups, often proven in the same way, just with sums replaced by integrals against Haar measure.  [Simon - Representations of finite and compact groups](https://doi.org/10.1038/383266a0) is a good reference, though it has some mistakes (just typos, maybe—I don't remember exactly).  … Actually, all this is assuming that you want *complex* representations.  If not, then maybe you could say more about what you want.

Comment: @LSpice: It seems your link is directing to a different web page than intended.

Comment: @LSpice: I have edited a little my question with the real motivation of my question. Maybe this will help to clarify what is needed. Thanks for taking your time on the reference stated!

Comment: By definition $SL_2(K)$ has a two-dimensional representation…

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436703/theory-of-group-representation-for-compact-groups#comment1125474_436703), it depends on the field—certainly all groups have 2D isotrivial representations over all fields, and $\operatorname{SL}_2(K)$ has a non-isotrivial 2D representation over $K$ (which appears to cover the cases of interest, since, for $K = \mathbb R$ and for $K = \mathbb C$, we get a complex representation thereby), but $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$, for example, has no non-isotrivial 2D complex representation.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436703/theory-of-group-representation-for-compact-groups#comment1125470_436703), your motivation suggests that you are interested in complex representations, but you seem not to be saying so explicitly.

Comment: @M.G., [thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436703/theory-of-group-representation-for-compact-groups#comment1125469_436703).  I grab my references off [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1363490), which, for some reason, seems accidentally to sneak in a paper in an entirely wrong discipline from time to time.  I will file a bug report.  I can't edit my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1125454) now, but the correct link seems to be [Simon - Representations of finite and compact groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/gsm/010).

Comment: You are asking two quite different questions, with different answers: $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ are not compact, so the classical repn theory (on complex vector spaces) of _compact_ Lie or topological groups (Weyl et al) does not apply... but Bargmann and Wigner studied those specific groups, and there are quite nice results (though quite different from the compact case). As in other comments: what are you really wanting?

Comment: @paul garrett: right, my mistake. My question is not very precise, so let's reformulate: is there some classical compact group (like SU(2,R)) in which we can classify all irreducible representations (or to make sense of that) and have the same behaviour as the one stated by Frobenius Theorem? Of course to make sense to my question, one needs to have all the technology of representation of compact groups or, in more general setting, a theory generalizing what is known for the finite case.

Comment: @JohnnyCage: the representations (if you mean, finite-dimensional over the complex numbers) of classical Lie groups have been very well understood for ~100 years. Almost any intro textbook on representation theory (e.g. the one by Fulton--Harris) explains this. But I don't know of any analogue of the theorem by Frobenius you mention...

Comment: @LSpice You saying that you get your references off MSN made me do a double take before I understood. What’s next, AIM bibliography managers?